# Is it possible to save a multiple image transitions as a video format like mp4 or mov?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have done different transitions from multiple images but I can't save these transition as a video format. Please help me any idea or link. This is my default transition and I wanna save this transition as a video format like mp4/mov.Thanks in advance.

```
NSArray * imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"],
                        nil];
UIImageView *instructions = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
instructions.animationImages = imageArray;
instructions.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
instructions.animationDuration = 5.0;
instructions.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[instructions startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:instructions];
```

Comment: you want to do it programmatically ?

Comment: yes. I want to do it programmatically. But  I can't understand  how to do it.